# Three threads, three sentences, right order

Tags: java, multithreading

How do we write the Java code that would display the following 3 sentences in the described order using a **different threads** for printing each sentence?

Can somebody explain with an example?

```
Hello there. 
How are you? 
Thank you, very much!
```

Comment: What code have you attempted so far?

Comment: IMO, your question is like asking, "How can we use a car to take a pleasant stroll in the park?" It subverts the entire point of threads which is, to let different processes take place _independently_ of one another. The best way, _by far_, to make any sequence of things happen in a particular order, is to do all of those things in the same thread.  Use multiple threads when you need to perform multiple processes at the same time, and it does not matter in which order the steps of the different processes are interleaved.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of solutions. In my opinion one of the most verbose but simple to understand and basic in concept is to just start three separate threads and wait for them to finish with a `thread.join`. Alternatively you could use solutions that make use of higher level API's like count down latches or locks.

This would look like:

```
final Thread first = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Hello there."));
        final Thread second = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("How are you?"));
        final Thread third = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Thank you, very much!"));
        first.start();
        first.join();
        second.start();
        second.join();
        third.start();
        third.join();
```

Output:

> Hello there.
>
> How are you?
>
> Thank you, very much!

This is very verbose and the most basic low level in my opinion. There are cleaner examples that could make use of different paradigms like actors with message passing. Or using count down latches to wait for other threads to finish. You could use wait and notify or there might be some other elegant solution.  What are you trying to achieve beyond this sample?

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more complex way:

```
public class Sentences {

    private static final String[] sentences = {
            "Hello there.",
            "How are you?",
            "Thank you, very much!"
    };
    private static int currentIndex = 0;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            new Thread(Sentences::say).start();
        }
    }

    private static synchronized void say() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " says: " + sentences[currentIndex++]);
    }

}
```

By removing the `synchronized` keyword, you might see how things can go wrong by executing the main method again and again. Sometimes the output is correct. Sometimes the order is wrong. And sometimes one line is missing and another one printed twice. Welcome to Pandora's box ;-)